# Limit of an involution at the extremities

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inverse-function

Let $f:]a,b[\to ]a,b[$ an involution not necessarily continuous . It's true that
$$\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)=a\iff \lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)=b\quad  ?$$
I can't find any counterexample

**Addition: Question resolved**

Comment: If continuity is not necessary then cant you just define such function piece wise ? (downvote is not me )

Comment: If I knew I wouldn't ask the question . Can u give me conterexample if a=0 et b=$+\infty$

Comment: No, I have been thinking about this problem here and there, and it is not so obvious to me anymore

Comment: How did you prove it?

Comment: Example if $a=-\infty$ and b=$+\infty$. 

**Let f defined on $\mathbb Z$ by** 

f (n) = -2n if n is positive,


f (n) = n if n is negative and odd,


f (n) = -n / 2 if n is negative and even.

**and f defined on** $\mathbb R^*_+$ \ $\mathbb Z$ **by** $f(x)=-x$